# I can't understand following python scientific notation

Tags: python

why this code output isn't true

```
bn, nbn, smn = 1e+15, -1e+15, 1e-15
print(bn + nbn + smn == smn + bn + nbn) 
#this print false
```

please explain it

Comment: `1e+15 + (-1e+15)` is `1e+15` because of the limited precision of floats.

Comment: I don't think commutativity from floating-point numbers is a reasonable expectation

Comment: @ThierryLathuille `1e+15 + (-1e+15)` evaluates to zero. Did you mean something different?

Comment: use `print(bn + nbn + smn, smn + bn + nbn)` and you will see different values `1e-15` and `0.0` Problem is that computer can't keep every float value and it keep only approximation and even `0.1 + 0.2 == 0.3` gives `False`

Comment: @khelwood Oh, yes :/ I meant 1e+15 + 1e-15... Thanks!